# Looking for the full text of "Faltings, A proof for the Verlinde formula. J. Algebraic Geom. 3 (1994), no. 2, 347-374."

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, conformal-field-theory

In am looking for the full text of the article by Faltings but could not find in anywhere so far.
The Journal of Algebraic Geometry is provided online starting in 2002 and I cannot find any of the older issues.
Does anyone know where to find the article?

Comment: If you're in a university, I'd check with its library. Even if the library itself doesn't have a copy, the librarians can often order copies from other libraries.

Comment: You might want to cross post this to MO. Professional mathematicians there might have a link to a scanned copy of the article or might even want to send you the copy in person.

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended up asking the librarian for help.